# Angular4-JsonEditor css is missing

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, sass

I am using Angular4-JsonEditor from https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-jsoneditor.

I am able to see the the **JSON** in tree format. I have also imported **css** as mentioned but some how the styling is not getting applied. it shows something like below. Even if I try to add my own styling to the existing classes , no changes are getting applied.I am new to angular can some one please guide me.

[image]

**app.component.ts**

```
 import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
 import { NgJsonEditorModule } from 'ang-jsoneditor' ;

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `<json-editor [options]="editorOptions" [data]="data"></json-
 editor>`,
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
export class AppComponent {
public editorOptions: JsonEditorOptions;
public data: any;
@ViewChild(JsonEditorComponent) editor: JsonEditorComponent;

 constructor() { 

var options = {
  "mode": "tree",
  "search": true
};
this.editorOptions = new JsonEditorOptions();
this.editorOptions.mode="view";
this.editorOptions.search=false;


this.data={"products":[{"name":"car","product":[{"name":"honda","model":
[{"id":"civic","name":"civic"},{"id":"accord","name":"accord"},
{"id":"crv","name":"crv"},{"id":"pilot","name":"pilot"},
{"id":"odyssey","name":"odyssey"}]}]}]}
}
}
```

}

**app.component.css**

```
 @import "~jsoneditor/dist/jsoneditor.min.css";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the import to `src/style.css`

```
@import "~jsoneditor/dist/jsoneditor.min.css";
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.. why it did not work when i have added it to app.component.css ? oi had given this in styleUrls for that component?

Comment: It's about the time of execution. Style.css runs first.